# Android slide animation with a bounce

Tags: android

I'm wanting to add a bounce to my animation in between activities by having the view slide from 100% to 0% on the current activity, then 0% to 115% and then quickly back to 100% on the new activity. I thought I could do this by adding a third slide animation that goes from 115% to 100%, but it wouldn't let me use 3 animations in the code below.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide, R.anim.slide2);
            finish();
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: have you tried this interpolater for your animation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnticipateOvershootInterpolator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place what you have for slide and slide 1 in a single XML file and reference that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:ordering="sequentially">

<one slide>
<another slide>

</set>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it isn't working, maybe the two animations are cancelling each other out since it just goes from 0% to 100% and the bounce doesn't show.

Comment: Then add a start delay to the second one: "android:startOffset="500" replace 500 with the length of the first animation

Comment: I did put the offset in.

Comment: @MDubzem See his answer again !

Comment: @MDubzem Take another look. mmlooloo added in another bit that should work - I learned something new here as well. Thank you mmlooloo

Comment: Just did some testing and I think the problem is that the layout won't go up above 100%, I tried making one animation that goes to 150% and it just stopped at 100%.

Comment: @MDubzem interesting. That's weird. I know that you can make stuff go above and below the screen...

Comment: Got it working, I found out that the two different animations in overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide, R.anim.slide2); are actually for each activity, the new activity was being animated with the first one and the current was animating by the 2nd. I also found that 0% is centre for the layout so by going to -5% it lifted it up. I put the slide up and bounce down animation in the first one and then made a slide down and fade animation for the second.

Answer (score 0):

This will slide the new screen from bottom to top and bounces, put it in the anim folder, with a name such as in_from_bottom_bounce.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator" >
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

Usage: put this in the onCreate method of the activity.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_bottom_bounce, 0);
```